# How to get out of for loop at the end of the loop and enter in a new without making the sum

Tags: java, arrays, methods

Here is my code. I have to count the frequency of letters in my text.
I got as output:
a  21
b  28(should be 7)
c  34(should be 6)

I think my problem is it makes the sum and i dont want it.

```
int[] alphabetArray = new int[26];    
    // char varA = 'a';    
    alphabetArray[0] = A;``

    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
        if (text[i] == A) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println((char) alphabetArray[0] + " kommt " + count + " Mal");

    alphabetArray[1] = B;

    for (int i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
        if (text[i] == B) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println((char) alphabetArray[1] + " kommt " + count + " Mal");
    alphabetArray[2] = C;
    for (int i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
        if (text[i] == C) {
            count++;    
         }
    }
    System.out.println((char) alphabetArray[2] + " kommt " + count + " Mal");

    return null;
```

Comment: You should set `count` to `0` after each print statement.

Comment: so dou you mind i have to declare count in each loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you could fix your problem by zeroing out the `count` after printing, your program would not be ideal with the loop itself repeated three times. When you see a pattern like this, it's an indication that you need another loop.

Make a loop *outside* your current loop going through the letters from `'A'` to `'Z'`. Since letters' code points in UNICODE are consecutive, you can find the index of a letter by subtracting `'A'` from it:

```
for (char letter = 'A' ; letter <= 'Z' ; letter++) {
    int letterIndex = letter - 'A';
    for (int i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
        if (text[i] == letter) {
            alphabetArray[letterIndex]++;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that since you are accumulating counts for all letters, you do not need a separate `count` variable, because `alphabetArray[letterIndex]` replaces it. If you want to print letter frequency as you go, print `alphabetArray[letterIndex]` after the nested loop.

Comment: just one question :why  letterIndex = letter - 'A' ? i didnt understand  here

Comment: @sitm Variable `letter` represents a numeric UNICODE code point of a letter. Numeric code points of letters `A` through `Z` are consecutive numbers. This means that you can subtract the number of the letter with the lowest code point from `letter` to find how far the letter is from `A`. For `B` you'd get `'B'-'A'==1`, for `C` you'd get `'C'-'A'==2`, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You initialized count=0 once and you are increasing it without re-initalizing it to 0.

```
int[] alphabetArray = new int[26];    
// char varA = 'a';    
alphabetArray[0] = A;``

int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
    if (text[i] == A) {
        count++;
    }
}
System.out.println((char) alphabetArray[0] + " kommt " + count + " Mal");

alphabetArray[1] = B;
count=0;
for (int i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
    if (text[i] == B) {
        count++;
    }
}
System.out.println((char) alphabetArray[1] + " kommt " + count + " Mal");
alphabetArray[2] = C;
count=0;
for (int i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
    if (text[i] == C) {
        count++;    
     }
}
System.out.println((char) alphabetArray[2] + " kommt " + count + " Mal");

return null;
```

Comment: thank you alot it works now! And any hint if i want to do switch instead for? because it can be long with that loop  till the letter Z!

Comment: you simply wants to count the occurrence of characters in a particular string. One way is create a int array of size 26 and whenever you finds the character increment it and finally you will get the occurence of every character. But if you want specific one then use hashmap of string as key and integer as value, so whenever you find just put it into it and if it exist just increae the count. If this helps mark it as answer so that others can easily refer to it.

Comment: Using a hasmap is a good idea i just would like to do without using it but i think i will do if i dont have any others solutions :)

Comment: sure you should always try to get the problem soved on your own :)